# removing gap between div border and font

Tags: css, fonts

Here's my CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid
  font-size: 30px
  color: red
  width: fit-content
  height: fit-content
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div>&#11165;</div>
```

Here's how it shows up in the browser:

[image]

Here it is on JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/f9wkb4qp/

I'd like to remove the gap between the div border and the font. eg. I'd like to make the result look more like this:

[image]

Any ideas as to how I might achieve this effect? Or is this even possible? Like if the white space is actually part of the character then I guess it might not be possible?

Comment: don't rely on fonts for this, either use an SVG or built it using CSS (clip-path can easily do it here)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `line-height`.

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    width: fit-content;
    line-height: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div>&#11165;</div>
```